# How can we access the data from ServiceStack's JSON Serializer when an error occurs?

Tags: c#, json, error-handling, deserialization, servicestack

How do we get more information about the JSON De-serialization exceptions when [ServiceStack's JSON Serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) is configured to throw on exceptions with:

```
JsConfig.ThrowOnDeserializationError = true;
```

By default the JSON Serializer will log and ignore non-critical exceptions or can be configured to throw with the above config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [ServiceStack's JSON Serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) is configured to throw when it encounters a de-serialization error, with:

```
JsConfig.ThrowOnDeserializationError = true;
```

It captures the information it was able to de-serialize and stores them in the `ex.Data` Dictionary in the thrown Serialization Exception.

```
try {
    string json = @"{""idBad"":""abc"", ""idGood"":""2"" }";
    JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(json, typeof(TestDto));
    Assert.Fail("Exception should have been thrown.");
} catch (SerializationException ex) {
    Assert.That(ex.Data, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(ex.Data["propertyName"], Is.EqualTo("idBad"));
    Assert.That(ex.Data["propertyValueString"], Is.EqualTo("abc"));
    Assert.That(ex.Data["propertyType"], Is.EqualTo(typeof(int)));
}
```